# How can I include interesting directory at specific target at cmake?

Tags: makefile, cmake

I have a question about Cmake.
When call target "helloAll", it build sub-target Hello and Hello2.
But each Hello and Hello2 should include other directory.
add_library() can include specific objects, but include_directory can not.
Do you have any solution?

Thank you very much!!

```
add_custom_target( helloAll DEPENDS Hello Hello2 )

#When building Hello include Src/inc
include_directories( Src/inc ) 

#When building Hello include Src/inc2
include_directories( Src/inc2 ) 

add_library( Hello Src/hello )
add_library( Hello2 Src/hello2 )

message(STATUS "CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR: ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR}")

build_command( buildCommand TARGET helloAll )
message(STATUS "buildCommand: ${buildCommand}")
```

Answer (score 0):

one CMakeLists.txt can't have each include_directory and each add_definitions about each target.
So, I write several CMakelists.txt about each include_directory and add_definitions.
I am not sure it is best solution. but this way can resolve this problem.

Thank you.